# start iphone 3d game programming

Tags: iphone, graphics, 3d

Hi
I am iphone developer, I already know iphone programming. I wrote couple of GPS based apps.
     Now I want to start learning 3D graphcis and game development. I want to make very simple games. ALso I want to learn how to make a solid object in Iphone.
Any suggestions where to start from ? ANy books etc ?

Comment: This question gets asked every other day. If you search this site, you'll find a ton of other related questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some good iPhone 3D / 2D OpenGL ES game tutorials?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148143/what-are-some-good-iphone-3d-2d-opengl-es-game-tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in commercial 3D game programming, I would recommend you take a look at http://unity3d.com. It simplifies a lot of problems, and you can start to play with a free version.

If your interest is in understanding the basics of 3D programming in the iPhone, you could start with the OpenGL ES Programming Guide (either the 2.0 version for iPhone 4 or the 1.x for 3G/GS).

Another book that seems good is: **iPhone 3D Programming: Developing Graphical Applications with OpenGL ES** although I haven't read it yet.

Comment: thanks but seems you missed the source you wanted to share " I would recommend you take a look at " .. Also can you recomend some book you followed ?

Comment: Sorry, it supposed to be Unity 3D which is a commercial game engine. I played a bit with it and it's very well done. They have a free version, but if you want to sell the game, you have to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Unity 3d. Its incredibly easy to use, and I made my first 3d game with it just last week!

Comment: Rushil can you let me the game you wrote.

Comment: ALso RUshil can you give some more info like how to get started ?

Comment: For information on gettings started check the unity tutorials here(http://unity3d.com/support/resources/example-projects/iphone-examples) or try the forum here(http://forum.unity3d.com/forums/27-iOS-Development) You can find my game here http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tommys-adventures/id391323894?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of working through the book ***Beginning iPhone Game Development*** (apress) which eventually goes through the development of an entire "2.5D" 3D asteroids type game. It sticks to relatively low-level stuff like OpenGL ES rather than teaching you something like Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Go for **Beginning iPhone Games Development** by Apress this one is more useful for those who started to develop game for iPhone. This book explores the basics of openGL ES for iphone game development.